# IIS Url Rewrite maps, get key by value?

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am doing inbound/outbound rewriting of urls and I have a map of all articleid --> url combinations. Now as I am doing it both ways I basically need to get the article id by url, but also get the url by article id.

To have this currently I need to have two rewrite maps, one for each way, but as there are quite a few articles, duplicating it would duplicate the size of the file with rewrite maps, and I am would really like to avoid that.

So my question is...is it possible to get as you get value by key:

{MyMap:812}

that I write somehow:

{MyMap:some_article.aspx}

and that it gets the 812 for me?

without having two different rewrite maps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not built-in, however, one way would be to write a custom provider that through code does the resolution, see the following link on how to achieve that:
[Developing URL Rewrite Providers](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/)

Comment: ok, and do you know how to access existing rewrite maps from a custom provider?